# In Visual Studio Code, outputing a "Hello World" function on C gives out "warning: return type defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]"

Tags: c

I'm new to programming and was using Visual Studio Code in C language to try out coding. I started with the Hello World function, but, even though the output was correct (the output was "Hello World!"), the following warning appeared. I don't know what it means: 
`[Running] cd "c:\Users\lucas\OneDrive\Ambiente de Trabalho\" && gcc test.c -o test && "c:\Users\lucas\OneDrive\Ambiente de Trabalho\"test
test.c:3:1: warning: return type defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]
    3 | main(){
      | ^~~~
Hello World
[Done] exited with code=0 in 0.71 seconds`

I used the code below to get the Hello World output:

```
#include<stdio.h>
main (){
    printf("Hello World!");
}
```

What should I do to fix this warning?
Thanks for the help!

Comment: `int main (){` is what you are looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explicitly give `main` a return type:

```
int main( void ) 
{
  printf ("Hello World!");
}
```

The standard signatures for `main` are

```
int main( void )
```

or

```
int main( int argc, char **argv ) // you can use different names for argc and argv
```

That is, either takes 0 or 2 parameters and returns an `int`.

In the early days of C, if you didn't provide a return type for a function, the compiler assumed it returned `int`.  Such implicit typing is no longer allowed, hence the warning.

Comment: Do you need `(void)` ?

Comment: If you're going to use prototype syntax *anywhere*, use it *everywhere*.  An empty parameter list in a function *definition* will be interpreted as "takes 0 parameters", but an empty parameter list in a *declaration* will be interpreted as "takes an unspecified number of parameters".  I'd rather be consistent and use the same form for both declarations and definitions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
I tried your first recommendation and it worket out great, without the warning!

Answer (score 1):

All functions must specify a return type.  Older version of C would allow the return type to be omitted, in which case the return type defaults to `int`.

The `main` function is particular **must** return `int`, so explicitly state as much.  Also, you need to return a value, and by convension `main` should return 0 if the program was successful.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    printf("Hello World!");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
I've tried that same exact code, including the "int" before main, but it still outputs the same warning.
Edit: I tried: int main(void) and it worked fine, without any warning. Why would that happen?

Answer (score 1):

Every function in C needs a return value type. With the main function, it can either be of type `void` or `int`. `void` means that the main function doesn't return a value. `int` means that the main function returns an integer. 
It looks like the compiler automatically filled in that part of your code with `int`, and it's just letting you know that you should actually be putting some return type.

So you can either do this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main (){
    printf("Hello World!");
    return 0;
}
```

Or this

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main (){
    printf("Hello World!");
}
```

Comment: `main` should always return an `int`

Comment: And either `EXIT_SUCCESS` or `EXIT_FAILURE`

Comment: Compilers may allow some backward compatibility, for embedded code which would never return from `main` anyway.

Comment: But it is better to get in good habits from the get go